# Как узнать значение scrollTop в самом низу блока, не делая прокрутки?

Tags: javascript

Как узнать значение scrollTop в самом низу блока, не делая прокрутки?

Знаю решение только с прокруткой:

[Пример на Liveweave](http://liveweave.com/RNot2L)

```js
function FF() {
  var el = document.getElementById("qq");
  var x = el.scrollLeft;
  var y = el.scrollTop;
  var z = el.scrollHeight;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "H: " + x + "px<br>Y: " + y + "px" + "<br>All:" + z;
}
```

```css
#qq {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}
```

```html
<div id="qq" onscroll="FF()">
  <div id="content">blabla</div>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: по игрику это и есть scrollTop, не? а икс стоит на месте.

Comment: scrollTop отображает текущую позицию, а хотелось бы узнать сколько всего без прокрутки.

Comment: offsetTop и другие https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates-document

Comment: Scrollheight minus clientheight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function FF() {
  var el = document.getElementById("qq");
  var x = el.offsetTop;
  var y = el.scrollTop;
  var z = el.scrollHeight;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "offsetTop(#qq): " + x + "px<br>scrollTop(#qq): " + y + "px" + "<br>All:" + z;
}

var result = document.getElementById('result');
var qq = document.getElementById('qq');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var scrollTop = content.clientHeight - qq.clientHeight;

result.innerText = "precalc scrollTop(#qq): " + scrollTop  + "px";
```

```css
#qq {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9000px;
  left: -9000px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.hidden .measure {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="qq" onscroll="FF()">
  <div id="content">blabla</div>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо тебе добрый человек =)

Comment: @СергейРябинин, если вам помог ответить, пожалуйста, проголосуйте за него и отметьте как "Верный" (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Сделал из вашего примера `offsetTop` дива `#qq`:

```js
function FF() {
  var el = document.getElementById("qq");
  var x = el.offsetTop;
  var y = el.scrollTop;
  var z = el.scrollHeight;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "offsetTop(#qq): " + x + "px<br>scrollTop(#qq): " + y + "px" + "<br>All:" + z;
}
```

```css
#qq {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}
```

```html
<div id="qq" onscroll="FF()">
  <div id="content">blabla</div>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Дело в том что проблемы это не решает, совсем. К примеру нам станет известно что если прокрутить в самый низ то будет Y: 565px задача узнать этот размер не прокручивая.

Comment: По оформлению: стили лучше вынести в отдельное поле, а в html не нужно указывать `body` и все, что до него